# Why is my buffer not showing in QGIS 3.16.15?

Tags: qgis, buffer

I've recently tried to create a buffer around a dissolved vector polygon layer. Here's the vector polygon:

[image]

When I tried to create a buffer, it seemed to be working fine. I could enter a distance measure (meters or kilometers) so there wasn't the issue with degrees that one sometimes has because of wrong projections.

However, once the buffer was created, its extent turned out to be empty.

**Questions**:

1. What went wrong?
2. How can I create a buffer of 50 kilometers around the polygon correctly?

Comment: You should create Geodesic Buffers, see: https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/04/05/geodesic-buffers-in-qgis/

Comment: @Babel Thank you for the link, I will check it out. But shouldn't "regular" buffers work as well?

Comment: Of course, regular buffer will show you something - but not necessarily real-world distances, but completely wrong (heavily distorted) results. If that is not a problem for you, go ahead. Still, your question is unclear: we can't see what is going on, you should provide more details about what you did.